# I am trying to Route Devise users if they are not certain user type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is this considered ok? i didnt even know before_action takes a block but it did. Is there any better way of doing it?

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    :authenticate_admin!
    redirect_to retailer_dashboard_path if current_user.retailer?
    redirect_to supplier_dashboard_path if current_user.supplier?
  end

  def dashboard
    @admin = current_user
    @retailers = Retailer.all
    @suppliers = Supplier.all
  end


end
```

Comment: That `:authenticate_admin!` symbol isn't going to do anything, but you're otherwise fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `after_sign_in_path_for` method, with which you can defer redirect URL per user role.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.retailer?       
    retailer_dashboard_path
  elsif resource.supplier?      
    supplier_dashboard_path 
  else
    super
  end
end
```

This is the Devise way of redirecting user.
There is also a `after_sign_out_path_for` method.

Comment: where does this go? i saw that few times but i didn't understand. I would really appreciate it if you elaborate. also what is the resource?

Comment: Most preferably in `application_controller.rb`.

Comment: `resource` is kind of the `current_user`. Devise internally call is resource as it supports multiple model for authentication.

Comment: So application controller pulls all the controllers in a rails app? so i can open a method from another controller there and modify it without touching the original controller?

Comment: Not all. Devise uses ApllicationController as  it's base. So some devise methods can be overridden from there. For other methods (like main registration/login logic) you'll have to override specific controller.